# Restrict customers being able to view a category/plp

Tags: spartacus-storefront

What is the suggested approach to restrict a customer viewing a PLP, based on the user group assigned to the CategoryModel?

For example, let's say a category with code "c012345" is assigned to the user group "promoPreviewCustomers". I have two registered customers who are a part of the customergroup but only one customer is in the promoPreviewCustomers group.

Only the customer who is in a promoPreviewCustomers group, should be able to see the PLP of the category page c012345.

Our initial thought was to drive this through a personalisation rule within Commerce.

What are other people's thoughts on how this should be implemented within Spartacus, given that the product search API does not take into account the logged in customer?

Answer (score 0):

Any restriction done only in Spartacus will be only for the UX as true restriction can only be done in the backend. Therefore, the best approach would be to drive this behavior with personalization within Commerce